# How to avoid/solve node-gyp error during npm install on macos?

Tags: node.js, npm, macos-high-sierra, node-gyp, bunyan

I am trying to install bunyan:

```
$ npm init
$ npm install bunyan

> dtrace-provider@0.8.7 install /PATH2/test2/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

make: Entering directory '/PATH2/test2/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build'
make: *** [ndtp.target.mk:22: .] Abort trap: 6
make: Leaving directory '/PATH2/test2/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/PATH/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/PATH/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node" "/PATH/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /PATH2/test2/node_modules/dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN test2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN test2@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 20 packages from 64 contributors and audited 23 packages in 3.185s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Current versions:

```
node -v => v10.16.0
npm -v => 6.9.0
python -V => Python 2.7.16
xcodebuild -version => Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

I am trying it on mac os (on debian it works OK.)
At first time problem was because python 3, I replaced it on python 2, then updated xcode and node-gyp, also tried to install the latest node https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/node-v10.16.0.pkg ,
but still problems.

Could you please help to solve this issue?

Comment: try to install with sudo `sudo npm install bunyan`

Comment: @SaurabhMistry also errors